# My model is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Why is the model null? 
I think my method is wrong and its not passing the data to the view

My Controller

```
public ActionResult AnnounceRead()
{
    using (var db = new HarmonyMainServerDbContext())
    {
        var announceList = from r in db.Announcer
                           select new { r.AnnounceTitle, r.AnnounceLink, };
        return View("Index", announceList);
    }
}
```

MY VIEW

```
@model IEnumerable<Harmony.Models.ANNOUNCEMENT>
<ul>
    @if (Model != null) 
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)           
        {
            <li><a href="@item.AnnounceLink"> Title: @item.AnnounceTitle</a></li>                 
        }        
    }                
</ul>
```

My Model

```
public class ANNOUNCEMENT
{
    [Key]
    public int AnnounceID { get; set; }
    public string AnnounceTitle { get; set; }
    public string AnnounceRemarks { get; set; }
    public string AnnounceLink { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: well the view will try to evaluate the result after you did dispose the `db` context ... so you should add a `.ToList()` inside the `using (var db = ...` block and all should be fine (btw: I would bet that it's a ObjectDisposed exception instead but maybe that got changed sometime ago)

Comment: Your creating an anonymous object (not `IEnumerable<ANNOUNCEMENT>`) and your code would result in an excetion. All you need is `return View("Index", db.Announcer.ToList());`

Answer (score 0):

```
var announceList = (from r in db.Announcer
                                   select new { r.AnnounceTitle, r.AnnounceLink }).ToList();
```

edit:
just add .ToList();

and if overhead not important and data is small just send db.Announcer

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult AnnounceRead()
 {
    using (var db = new HarmonyMainServerDbContext())
{
    var announceList = db.Announcer.Select(x=> new ANNOUNCEMENT{
                       AnnounceTitle = x.AnnounceTitle,
                       AnnounceLink = x.AnnounceLink
 }).ToList();

    return View("Index", announceList);
}
```

}

Comment: What is the point of creating a identical collection from the original collection  - it can be just `var announceList = db.Announcer.ToList();`

Comment: as he require only 2 properties as output AnnounceTitle ,AnnounceLink  instead of the whole model.

Comment: Make no difference - its just pointless extra overhead. And if you were to create a new object, the it should be a projected to a view model containing just those 2 properties